# Precheck recurring option with PayPal donation button

Tags: paypal

Paypal allows it to display a checkbox for recurring (monthly) donations.
If selected, it displays this checkbox:

[image: You can click here for monthly donations.]

I was wondering if I can precheck it so it's the default option.
So I set `src="1"` in the additional HTML variables as specified in the documentation ([Recurring payment variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables))

> Recurring payments. Subscription payments recur unless subscribers
> cancel their subscriptions before the end of the current billing cycle
> or you limit the number of times that payments recur with the value
> that you specify for srt.
>
> Valid value is:
>
> 0. Subscription payments do not recur.
> 1. Subscription payments recur.

But setting it to `1` does not precheck the checkbox. What effect has it then? And how can I achieve to precheck the recurring donation checkbox. Maybe this is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with a 'Donate' button flow

You could create a new 'Subscribe' button, which has a different flow and will always be recurring according to what it is set up for. Once you generate a button and copy its code, you can change its image to be whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "Subscribe" button would then mean not be able to use predefined sums in combination with the possibility to also add an individual amount as figuring in the screenshot, right?

Comment: Any amount selection would occur on your site